# Clickable points with openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I'm trying to have some very basic functionality with vector points with Openlayers 2.12 and I can't figure out how to track a click event on a point.

I create a map using the following code and add one point:

```
var map;
function init(){
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

    var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Satellite",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 22}
    );        

    map.addLayer(gsat);

    var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vector");

    vectorLayer.addFeatures(
        new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(-57.635021, -25.276987).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
            )
        )
    ) 

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(10.2, 48.9).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject()
        ), 2
    );        

    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Then, I've tried to identify when the point is clicked:

```
    // detect when points are clicked
    pointClick = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature(vectorLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point, 
    {eventListeners:{"click": clickNotice}};                                            
    map.addControl(pointClick);

    // detect point events 
    function clickNotice(evt) {
        alert('Point clicked');
        point.deactivate(); 
    }          

}
```

This is not working, (although I don't get any errors in Firebug), but I'm not sure of the correct syntax for handling points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GetFeature control designed for retrieve features from a server and fires events that notify applications of the selected features. In your case you should use SelectFeature control:

```
selectFeature = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    vectorLayer,
    {
        onSelect: clickNotice,
        autoActivate: true
    }
);
map.addControl(selectFeature);
```

Your example is not working beacause you have to activate GetFeature control before using it.

Answer (score 1):

@drnextgis is right. checkout this example [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/highlight-feature.html) for some inspiration.

i hope it helps you...